# jquery move background url order in css3 multiple background images?

Tags: jquery, css

I haven't been able to find anything on google, but is it possible to change the order of a background url with jquery on hover/click/whatever?

ie this:

```
background: 
    url('1st_bg.png') no-repeat center;
    url('2nd_bg.png') no-repeat center;
    url('3rd_bg.png') no-repeat center;
```

into this?

```
background: 
    url('3rd_bg.png') no-repeat center;
    url('2nd_bg.png') no-repeat center;
    url('1st_bg.png') no-repeat center;
```

using jquery?

I can't seem to figure out how to move my css around.. Any help would be very much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

LOOK At THIS :[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Px8qQ/5/)

HTML

```
<body class="image" id="BODY">
<button id="changeOrder" style="position:absolute;bottom:100px;left:100px">CHANGE IMAGE   ORDER</button>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.image {
background: url(http://radiantq.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/software_box.png) no-repeat 10px 10px, url(http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Flower-wallpaper-29.jpg) no-repeat 90px 90px, url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kEDW4tNSmpA/UYnb_TbNiqI/AAAAAAAAKlc/MuZ3D0k6xRs/s1600/wallpapers-of-Rose-Flower456.jpg) no-repeat 180px 180px;
background-size:100px 100px;
width:500px;
height: 500px;
}
.change {
background:url(http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Flower-wallpaper-29.jpg) no-repeat 10px 10px, url(http://radiantq.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/software_box.png) no-repeat 90px 90px, url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kEDW4tNSmpA/UYnb_TbNiqI/AAAAAAAAKlc/MuZ3D0k6xRs/s1600/wallpapers-of-Rose-Flower456.jpg) no-repeat 180px 180px;
background-size:100px 100px;
width:500px;
height: 500px;
}
```

JQUERY SCRIPT

```
$("#changeOrder").click(function () {
 $('#BODY').addClass('change');
});
```